# How to update an object in javascript

Tags: javascript, object

I have an object structure like below.

```
    bookmarks:""
    defaultcompany:"26740"
    defaultmarkets:defaultmarket:Array(6)
    0:{company: "3569", market: "29"}
    1:{company: "26740", market: "25"}
    2:{company: "2677", market: "3"}
    3:{company: "19878", market: "7"}
    4:{company: "1063", market: "1"}
    5:{company: "28215", market: "23"}
    length:6
    spotlightdays:"3"
    userid:"11130286"
```

How to update the object in javascript so that I can add one or more array elements under defaultMarket Array like below. I need to retain original values plus add some new ones? Also the existing array elements can also be modified.

```
    bookmarks:""
    defaultcompany:"26740"
    defaultmarkets:defaultmarket:Array(7)
    0:{company: "3569", market: "29"}
    1:{company: "26740", market: "25"}
    2:{company: "2677", market: "8"}
    3:{company: "19878", market: "7"}
    4:{company: "1063", market: "35"}
    5:{company: "28215", market: "23"}
    6:{company: "67890",market:"45"}
    length:7
    spotlightdays:"3"
    userid:"11130286"
```

Comment: Meet [Array.prototype.push()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push)

Comment: *"an object structure like below"* ? what's the object structure exactly ?

Comment: also in the second part of your code note there are `7` elements and your array has size `6`.

Comment: Using [Array.push()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) will solve it out.

Your code should be like `ObjectName.arrayName.push(newObject)`

Comment: Fixed the array.

Comment: What about editing the existing array elements?

Answer (score 0):

I believe these two functions will do what you want:

```js
var obj = {
  bookmarks: "",
  defaultcompany: "26740",
  defaultmarkets: {
    defaultmarket: [
      {company: "3569", market: "29"},
      {company: "26740", market: "25"},
      {company: "2677", market: "3"},
      {company: "19878", market: "7"},
      {company: "1063", market: "1"},
      {company: "28215", market: "23"}
    ]
  },
  length: 6,
  spotlightdays: "3",
  userid: "11130286"
}

// Add an object to the defaultmarket array
const addObject = newObj => obj.defaultmarkets.defaultmarket.push(newObj)

// Edit a market value in the defaultmarket array by the company value
const editMarketByCompany = (company, newValue) => {
  var arr = obj.defaultmarkets.defaultmarket
  arr[arr.findIndex(el => el.company === company)].market = newValue
}

addObject({company: "67890", market: "45"})
editMarketByCompany("2677", "8")

console.log(obj)
```

Answer (score -1):

It should be as simple as `obj.defaultmarkets.defaultmarket.push(elmToAdd)` if the given object is

`let obj = { bookmarks:""
    defaultcompany:"26740"
    defaultmarkets:defaultmarket:Array(6)
    0:{company: "3569", market: "29"}
    1:{company: "26740", market: "25"}
    2:{company: "2677", market: "8"}
    3:{company: "19878", market: "7"}
    4:{company: "1063", market: "35"}
    5:{company: "28215", market: "23"}
    6:{company: "67890",market:"45"
    length:6
    spotlightdays:"3"
    userid:"11130286"}`

Comment: What about modifying the existing array elemments? push will duplicate them